# Feedback on Maven multi-module project setup with OSGi

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, bnd

I am getting in touch with OSGi and trying to setup a project using Apache Felix and Maven. I'd like to use a Multi-Module build and declarative services. The project is hosted on GitHub: [osgi-maven-example](https://github.com/thomaseizinger/osgi-maven-example/tree/3a20cede2ccecd31f4760fe89417880cbcd34455) (Note that the link points to a specific commit and not to the HEAD of the repository.)

I have got a few questions about the overall setup of the project:

- According to [Neil Bartlett](http://njbartlett.name/2015/03/27/announcing-bnd-maven-plugin.html) the `bnd-maven-plugin` should preferably used over the Apache Felix Bnd Plugin because it respects Maven's lifecycle. Judging by the age of the bnd-maven-plugin, this seems to be a relatively new approach and I am therefore not sure if it is a good idea to do so.
- I am using the declarative services package (`org.apache.felix.scr.annotations`) from Apache Felix to define my components. These annotations are used by the `maven-scr-plugin` to generate service descriptors which are included in the `MANIFEST.MF` by the use of the following line in the `bnd.bnd` file: `Service-Component: OSGI-INF/*.xml`. Is this the way declarative services are intended to be used?
- IntelliJ displays a warning in the `GermanGreeter`-class: 
  [image: intellij-warning]
  What exactly does this mean? Do I need to care about this? How can I fix it?

Although I am pretty happy over this working example, I am curious if I am using all these technologies in their intended way and I would be very grateful if I could get some feedback on the overall setup before I am starting to use it in a bigger project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now an official set of annotations for DS, under the package `org.osgi.service.component.annotations`. These annotations are packaged in the jar "compendium" (org.osgi/cmpn), and bnd has a directive to generate components descriptors : `-dsannotations : *`

the first part of your question is subject to opinions... `maven-bundle-plugin` is more "maven centric" : it's more easy to integrate it in a maven build. `bnd-maven-plugin` is more "bnd centric" : you manipulate standard bnd files, but it broke some maven convention. both have advantage and inconvenient

Comment: Thank you for the hint to the official annotation package. Regarding the bnd plugin: Isn't exactly the other way round? As far as I know, does the bundle plugin create a jar on its own which is actually the job the jar plugin.

Comment: yes, maven-bundle-plugin define a new packaging and a new lifecycle, but this packaging is not mandatory (see the 'manifest' goal). bnd-maven-plugin is more simple to use, as it doesn't change the lifecycle/packaging, but it lacks others things. for example it's configuration doesn't follow "the maven way" (a single point of configuration - pom.xml), or inheriting configurations between projects (shared bnd file in a maven repo). both have pro & con

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jeremie that you should use the standardized annotations. They can be used with both the felix maven-bundle-plugin as well as the bnd-maven-plugin. For an example of the first see [Apache Karaf Tutorial part 10 - Declarative services](http://liquid-reality.de/Karaf-Tutorial/10/). For the second [this post from Neil](https://blogs.paremus.com/2015/03/announcing-the-bnd-maven-plugin/) is a good source of informations. You should not need the scr plugin.

The maven-bundle-plugin is quite stable and easy to use. The problem with it is that it redefines the maven lifecycle which can cause problems with some project setups. The bnd-maven-plugin needs a bit more maven xml in the parent but then has the advantage that it fits better into complex builds as it does not tweak maven.

Comment: I already read and also referenced this blog post in my question. However, if I do not configure the scr plugin, no service descriptors are generated and also the services do not start once I deploy the bundles.

Comment: You need to enable the spec annotation support. For both maven-bundle-plugin as well as bnd-maven-plugin you can do this in the bnd.bnd file using "-dsannotations: *". Like Jeremy explained... and of course you need to then use the spec annotations

Comment: I already have this line in my .bnd file. So it should work as soon as I switch to the official annotations?

Comment: As soon as I used the official annotations the service descriptors are generated automatically, thanks!

Comment: The links in your answer are broken.

Comment: I fixed the links